# How to override brace completion visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to implement my own version of brace completion in a visual studio extension as I need to be able to filter when it occurs.

```
[Export(typeof(IBraceCompletionContextProvider))]
public class CollabBrace : IBraceCompletionContextProvider {
    public bool TryCreateContext(ITextView textView, SnapshotPoint openingPoint, char openingBrace, char closingBrace, out IBraceCompletionContext context) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IBraceCompletionSessionProvider))]
[ContentType("text")]
[BracePair('{', '}')]
[BracePair('[', ']')]
public class CollabBrace2 : IBraceCompletionSessionProvider {
    public bool TryCreateSession(ITextView textView, SnapshotPoint openingPoint, char openingBrace, char closingBrace, out IBraceCompletionSession session) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here are the two way's I have tried to get the Context and Session of brace completion but they never fire.

Any examples or help would be greatly appreciated.